# Different between ionic class and ionic tag

Tags: ionic-framework

I am tried to learn ionic 2 but it is very difficult to me because they are used typescript, so I tried to learn Ionic 1 but I have lots of confusion there, two types of different in every html content for example, for creating header I have found below two methods, which I must use? when use?

**Ionic tag**

```
<ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
  <h1 class="title">Checkboxes</h1>
</ion-header-bar>
```

**Normal class applied in div**

```
<div class="bar bar-header">
   <h1 class="title">Header</h1>
</div>
```